# Easy way to explain "meet" versus "to meet" versus "meeting" versus "to meeting"

Tags: gerunds

I'm tutoring a native Chinese speaker and having some trouble expressing the different forms of gerunds versus infinitives, specifically in the following examples.  I can answer the questions myself intuitively, but I don't have a good way of explaining when to use one versus the other. Can any of you explain these questions? Are there any tricks to decide which to use?

[image]

Comment: I believe it's a matter of verb government which should be memorized with each new verb. "stop" requires +ing, "start" can take both to-infinitiva and verb+ing. I don't think there's an easy rule for this.

Comment: No, there's no rule; every verb is different in what kind of complement clause it can appear with. See [Complements](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf), plus the [Logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) and [Verb Phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) study guides, for more details. When you're familiar with that, the varieties of Noun phrase movements and deletions become important, and that's discussed with solved exercises in the Cliff's on [Equi and Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Comment: I think this is a great question, and particularly suited to the ELL site. If they close it there, you can post it here again.

Comment: From a learner's point of view, telling them the difference between *stop to think* and *stop thinking* or between *stop smoking* and *stop to smoke*, carefully, works best. This can work even without having to use any terminology.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I don't agree. Iis a false distinction. *Stop to Y* really means *Stop Xing to Y*. Teaching *stop to Y* gives learners the false idea that *stop* can have an infinitive as a complement. It can't. The *to  Y* phrase is just some extra information. It is that same thing as *I studied to improve my English*. The phrase *to improve my English* is just a bit of extra information - it has nothing to do with the verb *study*. If you teach students 'infinitives of purpose' then you don't need to teach this false distinction about *stop*! And your students won't get confused :)

Answer (score 2):

Remember to X/ forget to X:

- the remembering should happen before the doing.

Remember doing/ forget doing:

- you can or can't replay the video in your mind.

Used to do, be used to doing:

- *NEVER* teach these forms together, however tempted you feel. It just causes *cross-association* which a a dangerous form of linking things in the brain. Once this happens it can never be undone: *HEALTH WARNING: DON'T DO IT!*

Besides this, in "*I am used to going to bed early*", ***used to*** is an *adjective + preposition* combination. It is not a *verb + infinitive* combination. Of course, you'll never need to make the distinction for your students, because they'll never ever study them together! Teach the *adjective + preposition* combination with other *adjective + preposition* combinations (*fed up with*, *angry about* and so forth). Teach the verb as a verb. That adjective should not be in the list of other verbs in the execrise.

Stop doing / stop to do:

- It's better not to teach this distinction. It has nothing to do with the verb *stop*. The first is a normal use of the verb *stop* with another verb as complement. The second is just a use of the verb *stop* with no complement at all. It is just followed by an *infinitive of purpose*. See [here for more information](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62215/stop-working-vs-stopped-to-work/192325#192325.)

There *are* some generalisations that can be made about infinitive and -*ing* forms, but they are difficult to understand conceptually, and are not accurate enough to be very helpful. The best way to go about dealing with the problem is to remember that is that it generally depends on the preceding verb. It is better to learn and record this vocabulary in complete phrases or sentences ( - catchy ones). So students should record *remember to do* in an interesting sentence, not just the word *remember*. This goes for all new vocabulary, really.

Answer (score 1):

The class of verbal concepts involved is called nonfinite clause, where the clause is originated from a verb operating in a nonfinite mode.

The basis of a nonfinite is that its origin-verb is not anchored to any point in time, or in number of perpetrators.

- He came here *to die*.
- They came here *to die*.
- They are coming here *to die*.
- I will be coming here *to die*.

First, let me establish some premises, which you would probably already know, because it helps to understand the categorization. These are not the only nonfinites in English, but are the ones in question.

#### 1. Infinitive

The infinitive is still operating as a verb.

- I love **to paint** doors.

#### 2. To-less infinitive

Same premise of to-infinitive, without being fixated in tense or in number

- I propose that he **paint** doors.
  (note: "*I propose that he **paints** doors*" is bad grammar)
- I advise that he **apply** for the loan.
- I advise that they **apply** for the loan.

However, the following is not nonfinite, since we already know for a fact that it has already happened or is happening. Or, that our belief is grounded in time.

- I know that he paints doors. He paints doors.
- I believe that she saves money. She saves money and has two jobs.

#### 3. Present participle

They are adjectives or adverbs.

Adjectival present participle: used to describe a noun.

- Look at the **flying** fish.
- We are on a **winning** streak.

Adverbial present participle: used to describe the state of another action.

- He came home **running**. (Describes the action *came*)

Adverbial to the auxiliary verb

- He **is painting** the house.
- I **am eating** durian.
- He **is going** to go to school.
  (I'm poking fun at people's penchant for using *going to*)

#### 4. Gerunds

Gerunds are nouns. They are names of actions. They are neither adjectives nor adverbs.

Names of non-transitive actions.

- I enjoy **painting** and **walking**.

Names of transitive actions.

- I enjoy **painting** doors and **walking** my dog.

Name of a *possessable* action.

- I wish to thank you for your **painting** my doors and your **walking** my dog.
- I am furious at her **arriving** at work late everyday.
- My grandma appreciates my **holding** her hand every time I visit her.

Adverbial gerund

Where the gerund is not an adverb, but is described by an adverb.

- **Eating sloppily** is bad manners.

Adjectival gerunds.

Where the gerund is described by an adjective.

- Your **sloppy eating** reflects your bad manners.

#### 5. Verbal nouns

They are no longer actions. They are names of concrete products of actions.

Products of non-transitive actions.

- I wish to buy your **painting**.
- Bernie Maddoff has cheated me of my life's **savings**.
- I have to clean up his **shavings** from the sink everyday.
- "Friending" is the name of my favourite horse that will win the race.

Products of non-transitive prepositional actions. Has a preposition between the verbal noun and the subject of the verbal noun

- This is the **painting of** my grandma.
- They live in government **housing by** the river.

Concrete product of an action being an adjective

- The **painting** exhibition.
- I have a **savings** account with the **savings** bank.
- The **coupling** factory makes couplings for transmission cables.
- Similar to using a usual noun as adjective, e.g., **water** bottle.

---

#### Answer:

The best way is for your student to read, and read, and read. But if I were teaching a machine software some rules ....

Scoring ranks:
Au Gold = is grammatically acceptable
Ag Silver = is not logically awkward or out of alignment
Cu Copper = least number of words

1. I remember {} the Queen in the palace.

   - Obviously, using {to meeting} is not grammatically acceptable.
     Au = 0;
   - I remember {to meet with} the Queen in the palace.
     Au = 1;
     Ag = 0: because this is logically out of alignment. Being nonfinite the infinitive has no grounding in time, a sentence needs to provide the finite grounding in time of when the action is to take place.
     These do not need to be grounded in time, because it is your intention to let them continue ungrounded:
     I remember running. I take a painting. I like drapings. To meet the Queen is my fantasy.

   To fulfill your intentions to ground an infinitive in time, you would supply a finite verb
   I **will** remember {to meet} the Queen.
   I **did** remember {to meet} the Queen.
   I **remembered** {to meet} the Queen.
   I **struggled to** remember {to meet} the Queen.

   - I remember {meeting with} the Queen in the palace.
     Au = 1; Ag = 1; Cu = 0;
   - I remember {meeting} the Queen in the palace.
     Best score: Au = 1; Ag = 1; Cu = 1;
2. Did you remember {} the letter?

   - {post}
     Au = 0: not a nonfinite.
   - {to posting}
     Au = 0: not a nonfinite
   - {posting}
     Au = 1;
     Ag = 0;
     *Did you remember {} the letter?*
     is totally acceptable. It asks if you had any memory having posted a letter say while sitting in your car yesterday. But that is not what you intend to ask.
   - {to post}
     Highest possible score: Au = 1; Ag = 1; Cu = 0;
3. I am not used {} up early.
   Read about preposition-verb couplings: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202863/preposition-for-tie/202942#202942.

   We need a preposition {to} after *used*:
   I am not used {to {nonfinite} }.
   I am not familiar/familiarized {with {eating}} with chopsticks.
   I am not bothered {about {approving}} the XL pipeline.

   Without need of scoring:
   I am not used {to {getting}} up early.
4. Not the preposition-verb coupling as previous question.
   Plain to-infinitive:

   I used {to-infinitive} to the cinema.
   I trained {to get} up early.
   I remembered {to get} up early.

   - I used {get} up early.
     I used {go} to the cinema.
     Au = 0;
   - I used {getting} up early.
     I used {going} to the cinema.
     Au = 1;
     Ag = 0: not logical or not the intended message:
     I used getting up early as an excuse to avoid late nite parties.
     I used going to the cinema as excuse to see her.
   - I used {to go} to the cinema.
     Best score: Au = 1; Ag = 1; Cu = 1;
5. I regret {} Mary about the wedding of her ex-boyfriend.

   - I regret {tell} Mary about the wedding of her ex-boyfriend.
     Au = 0;
   - I regret {to telling} Mary about the wedding of her ex-boyfriend.
     Au = 0;
   - I regret {to tell} Mary about the wedding of her ex-boyfriend.
     Au = 1;
     Ag = 0: not the intended message, out of alignment in time/tense with the intended message
   - I regret {telling} Mary about the wedding of her ex-boyfriend.
     Best score: Au = 1; Ag = 1; Cu = 1;
6. I regret {} you that your loan application has been rejected.

   - 1. I regret {tell} you that your loan application has been rejected.
        Au = 0;
   - 1. I regret {to telling} you that your loan application has been rejected.
        Au = 0;
   - 1. I regret {to tell} you that your loan application has been rejected.
        Au = 1;
        Ag = 0: not the intended message, out of alignment in time/tense with the intended message
   - 1. I regret {telling} you that your loan application has been rejected.
        Best score: Au = 1; Ag = 1; Cu = 1;

---

Comment: Your *To-less infinitives* are in fact present  subjunctive forms. Your *adverbial to the auxiliary verb present participle* forms are generally treated as present continuous/progressive aspects of the verb.

Comment: Coincidence of infinitive with the subjunctive: *To be or not to be, which is the mystery of existence*.

Comment: Coincidence of the *form* of the infinitive with that of the subjunctive.

Comment: The subjunctive documents imaginary action, whatever forms it takes. Like real and imaginary numbers. Calling the subjunctive a *mood* is inadequate semantics. To be precise in semantics, the subjunctive operates in imaginary *mode*, rather than *mood*.

Comment: @Blesses Geek. Whether you call it a *mode* or a *mood*, it's not an infinitive.